# How to keep internal organs functioning within an exoskeleton suit in different gravity levels?

Tags: biology, robots, bio-mechanics

This question answers the issue I was wondering about of how well an exoskeleton suit could help my characters move as normal in higher and lower gravity [Could a robotic exoskeleton give humans Earth like movements on a high gravity planet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/79228/could-a-robotic-exoskeleton-give-humans-earth-like-movements-on-a-high-gravity-p)

The issue many member brought up is how the internal organs would suffer under higher gravity, or deteriorate in lower. Compression suits that pilots use to force the blood from the lower parts of the body back up to the brain is mentioned but also stated this isn't a perfect solution.

My characters eventually, later in the story will be a digital memory stored in a robotic body but I am using this exoskeleton phase to progress the story and for those characters to get used to and to realise why a fully robotic body is beneficial.

My question is what internal implants or other artificial adjustments can I make to their biological bodies to cope with being able to function at gravity levels of roughly 0.5g to 1.5g or slightly more?

Giving them oxygen masks is something they might need but what internally can be added to help them function along with their exoskeleton suit, or will they need so many artificial parts that they should jump straight to the fully robotic bodies?

Comment: First question - how long are they planning on staying in any of these environments, and what sort of readjustment to normal period are you going to need?  Multiple astronauts have lived in space for >1 year periods, it's just usually that the recovery period is pretty terrible (but you have an exosuit that can help with this already...).  If they keep transferring _rapidly_ between extreme gravity levels they're going to want that robot body, but if they have 10 years in between....

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse in terms of planetary missions its a few hours to a few days per mission, if they need recovery time as u suggest I can add that between missions but the characters in mind are also from different planets so I wanted to explore if they could exist all together in a rotating space habitat set at earth level gravity together? I am realising now that is complicating things further.

Comment: The best part about centrifugal-gravity space stations is that you have a gravity _gradient_; gravity is stronger the farther away from the center you are.  At the tech level of full exo or robot bodies, having multiple decks even in a "small" size station (eg, by offset counterbalances) is relatively trivial.  Everybody can live on the same station, and even visit their friends without too much trouble.  How long between planetary missions - at the extreme edges (.9g not being a concern)?

Comment: Other question - why fully transfer to a robot body?  Can they not remote-pilot the robot body with the exosuit?

Comment: The problem with different layers to house creatures used to different gravity is I cant have them interact as a community as well as I want to, the remote pilot is  a good idea haven't given enough thought to yet, I wanted the robot bodies because I want these characters to be near immortal, I aim to have the story and these characters to exist for insane predicted timescales past the trillions, quintillions of years.

Comment: ... then the reason they choose the robot bodies isn't _directly_ "all these planets are hard on us", it's "I'm getting old, and they have these new robot body things, so I can live longer".  That is, they've probably already done artificial organs or whatever, but will need to transfer to the robot body anyways.  Note that who/what made the space station, and how big/occupied it is is going to decide if there are (available) "nonstandard" gravity gradients.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I agree that is the realisation if they knew the long term but for now, living in the moment and without knowing the near omnipotence of the one that guides them, can there be that implant stage to maintain their biological bodies, or should the powerful computer take them straight to robotic bodies? for the stories sake I would like to explore the implants and exoskeleton stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your species has artificial organs which have been structurally reinforced, a possible solution would be to just secure your organs on with big magnets, preferably electromagnets. This could prevent the movement of organs in the body, and prevent them from deforming.

For the heart, if it was an artificial organ, the suit can provide feedback to the heart, telling it to beat harder or softer, depending on the gravity.

For muscles, to prevent atrophy and overuse, you can have the suit make movement harder (preventing atrophy) or help the wearer make them. For cardiovascular problems, [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/how-does-hypergravity-affect-the-human-body) might be the answer:

> There may be techniques that could mitigate some of the problems of prolonged exposure - e.g. **remaining immersed in water causes external pressure to mitigate a large part of the stress on cardiovascular system.**

If the suit was for geriatric purposes, like prolonging life, the suit could help repair organs, cells, or on a smaller scale, even genomes. It could help with exercise.

In short, I think if the suit was just for prolonging life, a simple exoskeleton would be fine. If it were for gravity, however, artificial organs would be the way to go.

I have no idea if this is the answer you wanted, but I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, that helps, some good ideas. Do you think there would be issues with their veins in higher g, i think i read somewhere there would be added pressure and they could burst?

Comment: I have no idea. It makes sense, though.